# Syntax question about FreeCodeCamp solidity video

Tags: solidity, arrays

Let `C` be a contract and `f` a function in it. Is there any reason to prefer

`C(address(C_array[_C_index])).f(_x);`
over
`C_array[_C_index].f(_x);`? They seem to be doing the same thing.

Comment: What are `C_array` and `_C_index`?

Comment: An array of contract `C`s and an integer index for the array.

Comment: Then you're correct the cast to address and back to C isn't needed at all.

Comment: @Ismael if you post this as an answer I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
C[] C_array;
uint256 _C_index;
```

Then you are correct the cast to address and back to C isn't needed at all. It perfectly fine to use it as

```
C_array[_C_index].f(_x)
```